# Is Mohammad Ali Jinnah the "Father of the Nation" of Pakistan?

Tags: pakistan, founding-fathers

[Wikipedia link says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_Ali_Jinnah):

> He is revered in Pakistan as Quaid-i-Azam ("Great Leader") and **Baba-i-Qaum**, ("Father of the Nation"). His birthday is a national holiday in Pakistan.

Is **Baba-i-Qaum** an official title?

What is the source of this information in Wikipedia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Wikipedia page notes, the title "Quaid-i-Azam" is an official title, given to  Jinnah by the Constituent Assembly in 1947, though it had been in use by associates and admirers of Jinnah before that and before independence.

By contrast, Baba-i-Quam seems to be a title that is widely and popularly used, like "First Lady" in the USA, or Alfred "the Great" of England. And like those unoffical titles, it can be used generally, including in "official" contexts, such as government websites and so forth